Uncertainties when fitting an image
I know how to fit a straight line to a set of 2d points with uncertainties on both coordinates, in order to obtain estimators, goodness-of-fit, and uncertainties - see for instance Press & Teukolsky http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/cip/6/3/10.1063/1.4823074
I am also learning how to detect lines in images (grids of intensities rather than sets of points as before), using edges, thresholds, and Hough space.  This provides estimators for the parameters of the lines, but what I don't understand is how to determine uncertainties on these estimators and goodness-of-fit.  Any suggestions?
In particular, I am not sure how to express uncertainties on the pixel intensities, which might allow me to build a chi2 and then determine uncertainties on the estimators.
